# How to track GCP API request parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an API Gateway set up with GCP. I am looking for a way to track the number of requests for each parameter specified in the API request.

For example the api receives 1200 GET requests for api.example.com/ex?special=true and 300 GET request for api.example.com/ex?counter=11 I'm looking for a way to see the metrics (number of requests) for each parameter (so special would be 1200 and counter would be 300).

Is logging the solution?

Comment: A good answer requires more information. If the query strings are being passed to the backends, I would modify the backends to store the details in a KV database. You can process the logs and parse the query strings. There are cost, performance and time factors to consider which are not present in your question.

Comment: What are the product that you use? Are those logs already logged (by you or the service that you use)?